# How to print all preview text showing in print preview in the final result of print?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that I want to print its content, I can see all the content of this tag in preview but when I print that It doesn't print all of the content!

It is worth mentioning some of the content portions overflowed in print preview and obviously it doesn't print in addition to this part some of the other parts that show in preview correctly don't show in the final result of print.
I tried page-break-before: always property, it doesn't work too!

[image]

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: Atleast share the images

Comment: here you go
@RanjitSingh

Comment: Try saving it as PDF once

Comment: Well PDF is ok, I save the print preview as a PDF file and I print it and it was ok, but how can I print that page like pdf result? 
@RanjitSingh

Comment: Its very strange, while its showing 2 sheet of paper, only 1 page is getting printed. Maybe something to do with print settings.